# Dynamically adding one object to another in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that needs to have another object added to it when a user selects a certain value.  The object is a player object that holds basic info, I also have a weapon object that holds the information about a weapon.  When a user makes a selection for a weapon to use, I would like to add the weapon object to the player object, if the user selects a different weapon, I'd like to remove the previous weapon object and add the new one.  Is this possible?  Would it be like pushing values into an array?

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option>Sword</option>
    <option>Axe</option>
    <option>Hammer</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
var Player = {
    name: "One",
    weapon:
}

var Sword = {
    type: "Bronze",
    speed: 1.25,
    min_damage: 15,
    max_damage: 20,
    str_required: 15,
    gems: "",
    hilt: "",
    blade: "",
    inscriptions: "",
    runes: ""
}

var Axe = {
    type: "Bronze",
    speed: 1.5,
    min_damage: 25,
    max_damage: 28,
    str_required: 25,
    gems: "",
    hilt: "",
    blade: "", 
    inscriptions: "",
    runes: ""
}

var Hammer = {
    type: "Bronze",
    speed: 2.5,
    min_damage: 45,
    max_damage: 60,
    str_required: 55,
    gems: "",
    hilt: "",
    blade: "", 
    inscriptions: "",
    runes: ""
}

$("select").on("change", function(){
    var selected_weapon = $(this).val();

    if(selected_weapon == "Sword"){
        Player.weapon = Sword;
        $("#content").append(Player);
    }
    else if(selected_weapon == "Axe"){
        Player.weapon = Axe;
        $("#content").append(Player);
    }
    else if(selected_weapon == "Hammer"){
        Player.weapon = Hammer;
        $("#content").append(Player);
    }
});
```

Comment: doesn't player.weapon = Hammer; work?

Comment: Since all of your weapons are the same class with different values, why not create a weapon object and simply have presets based on name?

Comment: And what isn't working exactly?

Comment: This is the kind of problem that would benefit greatly from the use of a data binding framework.

Comment: @JoelEtherton  I didn't think about that.  I'll probably do that now that you've mentioned it.  Would that solve my problem since I'm actually only loading one object?  Or would that create more issues?

Comment: @adeneo, the previous object isn't being removed.

Comment: @Robert: I don't really see that you have much of a problem really since JavaScript is prototyped the way it is, but it might make your code simpler when you start branching out to more complex weapons (which it looks like you're planning to do). If you have a weapon class that can create itself based on a set of options, then expanding them becomes much easier.

Comment: What do you mean it's not removed, if you do `Player.weapon = Hammer` it overwrites anything that `Player.weapon` contains. If you want to remove it all together, that would be `delete Player.weapon`

Comment: @JoelEtherton I do plan on making them more complex.  I'll do as you suggest and create a standard weapon class then pass in different options for each various weapon.  Thank you.

Comment: @adeneo It may be my browser then, could be caching or something or it.  If you see it working the way it already is, then I'll trust your word on it.  Thank for the help.

Comment: To whomever voted to close, it's pretty clear what my question is asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding existing objects to each other in JS is very easy.

In your case, `Player.weapon = Sword;`

That would give you

```
Player = {
    name: "One",
    weapon: {
        type: "Bronze",
        speed: 1.25,
        min_damage: 15,
        max_damage: 20,
        str_required: 15,
        gems: "",
        hilt: "",
        blade: "",
        inscriptions: "",
        runes: ""
    }
}
```

I'd recommend adding a `name` key to each weapon object though. Right now when you look at the `Player` object I have posted above, you don't know which weapon it has. So just adding `name: 'Sword'` would allow you to reference it later as needed.

Comment: Yes what you have is correct. So is something not working with your setup?

Comment: Right now it's not working on my browser.  It may be a chaching issue or it could be the browser itself.  Either way, at least it's working for others.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Whenever I'm actively developing, (especially in JavaScript), I keep Chrome DevTools open. If you go into settings (gear icon in top right), Under General, mark the checkbox "Disable cache (While DevTools is open)". That helps me quite a bit.

Comment: Keeping devtools open will also allow you to see any errors as they come up as well. I don't know what the settings are for other browsers. I feel Chrome is the best for developing.

Comment: Will do.  I should probably stop developing for Firefox and switch to Chrome.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would store your player's selected weapon in an empty array...

```
var Player = {
    name: "One",
    weapon: []
}
```

...and then push the weapon into the array.

```
Player.weapon.push({ name: 'Sword', obj: Sword });
```

If you want to empty the array before adding the new weapon you can do this...

```
Player.weapon.empty();
```

or...

```
Player.weapon = [];
```

You could do...

```
Player.weapon = Sword
```

...but then your player can only have one weapon selected. If you are doing it this way I would do this...

```
Player.weapon = { name: 'Sword', obj: Sword };
```

...or store a name property on your weapon objects.

Hope that helps

Comment: Didn't think about doing an object array, it actually seems like it'll be easier.  I'll try that out, thank you.